# Adding Subtitles to WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a beginner in WP,  I apologize if this is a silly question.  I am looking to add subtitles to each of my posts where I can then access them via the WP REST API.  I am using a plugin called Subtitles which seems to have good support.  I have copied the code below.

I am assuming I need to replace 'custom-post-type-slug' with something to make the below code work, but I have tried a number of things to no avail.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Here is the link to the plugin support as well which may be helpful https://github.com/professionalthemes/Subtitles/blob/master/README.md

```
function theme_slug_add_subtitles_support() {
add_post_type_support( 'custom-post-type-slug', 'subtitles' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'theme_slug_add_subtitles_support' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom post type? If so then you need to replace 'custom-post-type-slug' with the slug of your custom post type.

Where can you find the slug?

I believe that if you select the custom post type from the left hand admin menu, the slug name will shown at the top left of the page (as the title for the admin page that you're on).

And if it's not a custom post type (Just the regular posts section from the admin side), then according to your pluggins documentation the subheaders should already be added to your posts

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Sean,  I am not using a custom post type.  I may have misunderstood what thsi is doing,  Is this just adding the subtitles to the WP admin section?

Comment: I am looking to be able to access each posts subtitle via the WP REST API.  Is that possible?

Comment: Or will i have to create a custom post type in order to do this?

Comment: Do you see the subtitle field when viewing a post on the admin side? If so then everything should already be set up and the subtitle's would be a field of the default post type.  I've not used the WP REST API, so I can't say what they query would be. But I imagine that you should be targeting the posts type in the query, and then parse out the subtitle field from the JSON that is returned

Comment: When I look at a post object it doesnt seem to have a subtitle in the JSON that it is returning.  Any idea?

Comment: I do know in the database that there are two different sections for post and post_meta. And that the fields are stored in the post_meta section. Not sure if that helps or not as I've never used the REST API.